# Is chardetect.exe required for get request and content?

Tags: python-requests

is "chardetect.exe" executable required for a get request and content? Just wanted to know. If not needed, then is it okay to delete it so that I can store the chardet files in bitbucket/git without an executable?

Code to use:

```
req = requests.get(url)
with io.BytesIO() as buf:
    buf.write(req.content)
    buf.seek(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Requests currently requires the chardet package but doesn't rely on any of the CLI tools.
https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/5548#issuecomment-668228215